# Good alternative to PayPal's implicit payments (Adaptive payments) with Rails support?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, system, payment

My app got declined by PayPal due to the business model which uses implicit payments. What alternatives do I have to automatically send money from my app to users? My business is in Australia or I would look at Stripe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had positive experience with:
[Ogone](http://www.ogone.de/en)

They also support Australia, I think the payments would be done via dollars.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I am awaiting their response to see if they support this.